# Why do we need to return state from reducer in Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am new to Redux and was trying to get how to work with Redux properly but I encountered a confusion on why we need to return state in reducer. Here is the code:

```
const initialState = {
  counter: 0
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  if (action.type === "INCREMENT") {
    return {
      counter: state.counter + 1
    };
  }
  return state;  // why do we need to use this code?
};

export default reducer;
```

Comment: Because that's what the API requires?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, please can you clarify?

Comment: I don't know how else to put it. The API of a Redux reducer is that it returns a state. Maybe read https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers

Comment: we need to return the state so that your component where you connect to the store can get the store state,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the reducer gets the previous state of your predefined object as an argument and the function must return in every single case the new state of the object.

In the Redux reducers documentation you can see the following statement:

> The reducer is a pure function that takes the previous state and an action, and returns the next state.

Read further about [Handling actions](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#handling-actions) in Redux.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the docs,

> Reducers specify how the application's state changes in response to actions sent to the store. Remember that actions only describe what happened, but don't describe how the application's state changes.

So whenever you call an action, reducer must return a new state based on that action.
In your case, `(action.type === "INCREMENT)` if action.type doesn't match your cases and you haven't set any default case it will return `null value`.

Now your redux state will have no mention about your given state if you won't return any value that's why default state is needed to maintain state data in reducer store.